# Create option class for my own class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm working in a class library that does something according to the configuration set by the user in Setup.cs (I still dont konw which method fits better, `Configure` or `ConfigureServices`).

Soon, my library will be in nuget, users will can install it and configure it. Question is, how can create that options/config class, instantiate that class in Startup.cs (`Configure` or `ConfigureServices`) and pass that options to my class/lib/package?

Here goes my doubt in practice:

`Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyLib(s => s.Value = 1);
}
```

`Inside my class library/nuget package`

```
public class CalculationHelper
{
    public bool GetSomething()
    {
        if (Options.Value == 1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

`In extension method (DI)`

```
public static void AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection app, Action<Options> options = null)
{
    // Here in this Extension method, I need save this options that I can retrieve for my class library (CalculationHelper).
}
```

I have seen much libraries using this method of configuration, like, Swagger, AutoMapper, Serilog, etc.

This is as much as I can specify, I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
public class YourOptions {
    public int Value { get; set; } = SomeDefaultValue;
}

public class YourService : IYourService {
    private readonly YourOptions options;

    public YourService (YourOptions options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public bool GetSomething() {
        if (options.Value == 1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Create your extension method that allows for the option to be configured while adding you services.

```
public static class MyLibServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<YourOptions> configure = null) {
        //add custom options and allow for it to be configured
        if (configure == null) configure = o => { };
        services.AddOptions<YourOptions>().Configure(configure);
        services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<YourOptions>>().Value);

        //...add other custom service for example
        services.AddScoped<IYourService, YourService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Users of your library will then configure as needed

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddMyLib(options => options.Value = 1);

    //...
}
```

And when using your service

```
public SomeClass(IYourService service) {
    bool result = service.GetSomething();
}
```

Yes, the standard practice is to use `IOptions<T>`. I personally am not a fan of injecting that and tend to use the pattern modeled above. I do still register it for those who would still like to use it.